# Redis does not create socket file after installing

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, nginx, redis

I have redis installed with laravel script. But when im trying to access my site im getting error: `No such file or directory [unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock]`

Why so? In `/var/run/redis` directory there is only `redis-server.pid` file

Comment: Which OS installed on your server?

Comment: in redis.conf change your unixsocket path. https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/8081